# Can We use Scientific Relations in answers and questions?

Tags: discussion

Recently while I was answering a question, I was suggested that I need not use scientific relations in my answers.

Stories make beliefs, but proofs built theologies.

I know today's science is not stable enough to understand most of advanced features of our text books, as they are advance sciences, yet some low level things, which have a hand in proof can be used to make interpretations more solid.

Most of vastu and ayurveda related questions can be answered through science, and there are other similar agendas which if answered scientifically will not only clarify the intuitions but also rock the beliefs.

Comment: You will get your answer if you read this [answer](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/143/93).

Answer (score 3):

> Can We use Scientific Relations in answers and questions?

**- No** you cannot and you shouldn't.

Reason : Answers you contribute here or questions users ask should be scriptural in nature and not scientific. Science and Religion cannot be mixed. For example, according to Hinduism, lord Brahma is the creator and according to science, the creation is natural.

**But**

Science is based on experiments, proof, theories etc, where as religion is based on scriptures, vedic writings etc. If you want you can contribute a scientific reason as an alternative to your main answer **(if a user asks so)** which should be based on religion. So your answer should be like

> This is just a demo answer to a demo question where a user should
>   answer based on scripture or facts or beliefs and once he writes the
>   main answer, he can share a scientific reason for the same. 
>  **If
>   you want to know the scientific reason behind this** : 
> Here you should
>   provide your scientific answer

---

Short Answer: **No** you cannot scientifically answer a religious question **but** you can always include a scientific answer as an alternate in your main answer if users is keen to know a scientific reason as well but its not a compulsion, you can deny sharing a scientific answer if you don't know.

Also note that a user should not tick an answer (accepting) as correct based on scientific reason if he has asked for. Site is purely religion based hence you shouldn't judge answers based on science.

For more information you can refer this post

https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/143/93

Answer (score 0):

Hinduism is an **intrinsically scientific** religion.

The Vedas themselves accurately describe very complicated geometric concepts including six-dimensional spaces, distances between celestial bodies, and using changing skylines to measure time, just to name a few examples ("Vedic Geometry Course" Dr. S. K. Kapoor). If you follow the Dhashavataram carefully, you will see that it perfectly mirrors the evolution of life on Earth as well as the emergence of increased social structure (and eventual decline) among humans.

Furthermore, it has been written that the Vedas themselves are to be consulted only in matters which **cannot** be resolved by either *Pratyaksha* (direct observation) or *Anumana* (inferences and inductions based on said observations, or in other words **science**).

The third category of knowledge, *Sabda*, refers to the Vedas themselves. Smritis, Itihasas, and Puranas are also included here where they "do not contradict the Vedas". *Sabda* is to be relied on to resolve questions which either have not yet been answered by *Pratyaksha* and *Anumana* (e.g. how does physics behave in a six-dimensional space?) or cannot be answered (e.g. what happens to the *Atma* after death?).

Info above paraphrased from: "A Dialogue on Hinduism", Sri V. N. Gopala Desikan, pg. 24-25

In other words, Vedas and science do not contradict each other. They lie **orthogonal** to each other. Our gurus want us to use science to answer any worldly questions, and seek the Vedas for matters that science does not or cannot answer.

Ultimately, it makes **no sense** to disallow scientific answers since Hinduism is a very scientific religion. Many of our beliefs stem directly from scientific facts (ritual purity and not shaving during certain months just to name a few).

**EDIT** I've posted a Q&A on this topic here: [Does Science Contradict Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2816/does-science-contradict-hinduism) as I believe much of our discussion could be better suited on the main site itself. After all, this discussion feels more about the nature of Hinduism than the hinduism.stackexchange website.

Comment: you are right, but our scientific knowledge is too less, there would be many things which we would not be able to answer scientifically yet as Mr. Alien suggested you can continue with extra details having scientific correlations.

Comment: @KCloud That's definitely a good approach. Of course the site is primarily about Vedas so we will prefer to use scriptural reasoning for most if not all answers, but I simply want to emphasize that one does not rule out the other.