# Why we are allowing scientific answers?

Tags: discussion

According to this [answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/276/93), we are not allowing scientific answers but still I can see many answers which are purely based on scientific stuff but not giving importance to what exactly Hindu scriptures are saying.

I am really disappointed that many high rep and old users are answering  in science perception but not in Hindu's perception.

I can give many examples, here is the one:

[Why we don't eat non-veg, don't intake liquor and some people don't shave while Shravan Maas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2136/93)

Both the answers on this post are talking about science stuff.

My humble request to moderators is to not allow such answers and educate/prompt the users to not answer such stuff here.

and also let me know should I flag such answers?

Thanks.

Comment: Those particular answers are from the site's early days, back when the rules on scientific speculation and other matters weren't firmly established, so they're "grandfathered in".  If these answers were posted today, they would be deleted.

Comment: But I think these also must be deleted because if a new user post a scientific answer and when said not to do so, he/she will show these posts as an example.

Comment: @Mr.Green Well, if we enforce all the rules of the site retroactively, then we would have to delete almost all the content from the first few months of the site; a lot of answers back then were one line long (except me and Jabahar's answers :-)).

Comment: Well said and agreed. but at least leave a comment on posts like that please :)

Comment: Rather, why we are allowing scientific _questions_? When people ask questions seeking scientific proof, others attempt to answer with whatever science we know. An example is this question: [Did Ramayana occur 1.6 million years ago?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9009/did-ramayana-occur-1-6-million-years-ago) in which OP links four-tusked elephants from 1.6 million years ago with those mentioned in Ramayana. Neither of the answers really address four-tusked elephants correlation. As you can see, the problem is not with the answers but with the question.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan post notice can work for those one liner answers or even few can be made into comments.