# Science stack sites related questions hijacking Hindu questions

Tags: discussion

In continuation to [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/asking-for-hindu-references-containing-science-vs-asking-for-scientific-explanat) question. I got a big doubt.

Some people are arguing that any questions regarding science will not be encouraged in this site. It is rational to say that any question asking for scientific explanation is off topic. But it is irrational that a question asking for scientific reference from scriptures is off topic.

Modern mathematics, science, geography, medicine etc., are developed relatively very recent compared to Hindu scriptures. If we avoid those question on Hindu SE, even the Hindu texts contain about that sciences, because of the reason that they got separate SE, or not consistent with modern science, then some part of text from Hindu texts will become off topic.

And if in future the subjects like astrology, yoga etc., is accepted by scientific community and a separate stack site comes for that, will those questions become off topic later?

The science that present in texts may or may not be consistent with the science in Hindu texts. So science SE sites may not consider science that is in Hindu texts,  then what about such science in Hindu texts? no site deals with it right?

Isn't it a form of hijacking Hindu sciences, which are directly from scriptures?

Comment: I think the modern science is the different form of science than what we may find in scriptures. So, modern scientific questions would be off-topic. Actually what issue we occasionally find is "scientific speculation". Some modern people tries to interpret text in scientific way and that distorts the real concept. So, speculation is off-topic and not allowed here.

Comment: @Pandya I shall quote very authentic explanation of scientific topics from established scientists without any type of speculation from my side. Is that ok then? Check the faq and the sentence used is "Science is off-topic for HInduism.SE" but later while updating help center and adding close reasons, the word speculation is added. It's not modern science, medieval science or ancient science. The reason why it's off-topic is not speculating, it's because people here are not knowledgable about it and vote blindly and it's not cup of tea. We are not scientists to decide what is right or wrong.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, i think the problem is drawing the line between what is science and what is not.. jyothisha - science or not.. ayurveda - science or not. they are not asking for western scientific explanations - they can go to the other SE sites for that. they asking for scriptural scientific explanations. for instance, if someone wanted to know the scriptural way to levy taxes - should they go to government SE? No, because Manu Smritis have answer for that - like a bee takes nectar from flower without hurting, king should levy 1/6th (16%) of income as tax. we can use discretion

Comment: @ram That discretion is already done. People didn't understand it. Science is a vague for the word Shastra.It doesn't necessarily mean the "science" people use daily. "scriptural way..." you misunderstood me. Asking about what scriptures say and asking Hindu way of explaining science are different. How is water cycle formed, Brahma Purana has answer. How are bugs born, Brahmanda Purana has. All topics r present in Hindu scriptures but some are misleading and wrong. the question is if we the right site to ask and answer those questions. I also don't understand Hindu science, Christian science.