# Meta flag pending since Aug 26

Tags: support, moderators, flagging

> [Is asking for direct references containing science on-topic?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/is-asking-for-direct-references-containing-science-on-topic) [duplicate] asked Nov 11 '18 at 15:44 by hanugm
>
> this is not a dup of the other, needs to be reopened so it can be properly answered – sv. Aug 26 at 22:07 **pending**

Can the mods please take action on this flag one way or the other?

Comment: The flag is cleared now.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā - convert the comment into an answer; will accept it.