# Definition for science speculation to our main site

Tags: discussion

I read some questions and answers on our meta site to get an idea on scientific speculation. But did not get the whole idea.

My current ideas are as follows:

> 1. Any statement that completely belongs to science with no backup from
>    scriptures.
> 2. Or any statement from science that is under speculation with out any
>    evidence or proof.

I feel that second one is more apt for scientific speculation. But not sure about the actual definition for our main site.

So, please provide a proper definition for science speculation.

If I wrote an *valid scientific* interpretation for a scriptural statement, then can it be a scientific speculation?

Comment: `valid scientific interpretation` Any example?  Here is the [meta post link](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/142/93)

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43683/is-there-any-modern-interpretation-for-indras-curse-to-women-and-other-entities @Mr_Green

Comment: The above question link seems off-topic to me. If you mean `valid` by `making sense interpretation` then that is clearly off-topic. (_it might make sense to you and some but not to everyone_)

Comment: I mean, how can one say that it is invalid @Mr_Green because it is consistent with both science and scriptures! Although, if someone thinks that it is the wrong interpretation, but it is still a valid one right?

Comment: Valid in the sense: **allowed/possible** interpretation...

Comment: I agree with it but such interpretations could open doors to other possible interpretations of other stories/incidents that even you might not be comfortable with. It is not like you can't ask it on the internet - you can ask this anywhere (maybe other SEs) but not just here. It is better to respect such boundaries which define and keep the site goal-oriented and keep the community together.

Comment: People often feel lost if any post of their post is off-topic here but they should just move on and ask it wherever it is possibly welcomed.

Comment: @Mr_Greek yeah, I (partially) agree with it. But I feel, if it is not a good place to make such things, then there should be a closing mechanism, but scientific speculation may not be a correct tag. Else there should a strict guideline regarding it. So I asked this question

Comment: IMO, it does fall under scientific speculation. Also, there is a strict guideline regarding this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. if you mean `strict guideline` by something else, please explain.

Comment: @Mr_Green In my example, why do you feel that the question is scientific speculation? I never asked for scientific interpretation, it is any valid scriptural interpretation. If you have issues with my answer, then it can be slightly agreeable.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need/welcoming all modern interpretations like the one you already provided in the question. First of all, this seems too broad here as this is welcoming all modern speculations of gurus (_which could include different opinions - even scientific_). And also, the answer post is clearly concluding the behavior of the physical nature of the bodies you specified - which is actually scientific speculation. I would have no problem if the question was like "What are the effects of Indra's sin?" or asking for particular gurus interpretation maybe or something similar.

Comment: In other words, the answers you will get will be correlation of nature/behavior of bodies (**science**) with scriptural interpretations (**speculations**). I might be wrong but this what I sense.