# An edit proposed to the on-topic page of our help center

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

As we know, we have an on-topic page. This is shown as [*What topics can I ask about here?*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the help center.

This page helps the users to know which questions are on-topic and off-topic on our site.

Currently under the off-topic section, the reasons stated are:

> - Personal advice questions.
> - Scientific speculation.
> - Questions soliciting opinion.

I feel that it would be great if these are linked with relevant meta discussions. Adding them will help the new users understand why we consider such questions off-topic. This will reduce off-topic questions based on  Here are the relevant discussions for the first two reasons.

- [Asking for help / solutions to solve personal issues should be considered off-topic](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/296/5212)
- [Political and Scientific questions are off-topic for Hinduism SE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/121/5212)

**Why to add links? these posts are already linked in the close reasons.**

- Adding these links would help the users who visit the help center before posting on the main site.
- This saves their time and it decreases an off-topic question on our site.
- Reading the meta discussion clears a doubt in users which type of questions are personal advice, scientific speculation and which are not. So, they shall modify their questions to on-topic question or refrain from posting the question.

Many sites have linked their meta posts to on topic and off-topic reasons for the better understanding of the users.

So, I believe implementing this would help the users(specially new users).

Comment: yes it will be good.