# What's wrong with asking mentions of eclipse restrictions in Hindu scriptures?

Tags: discussion

This question is closed as offtopic [Why is Chandra Grahan (Lunar eclipse) considered unsafe for pregnant women in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3329/why-is-chandra-grahan-lunar-eclipse-considered-unsafe-for-pregnant-women-in-hi)

I don't understand why. please help me understand.  He is just asking about the mentions of this myth in Hindu scriptures.

This question ([Why are women restricted from entering temples during menstruation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11321/why-are-women-restricted-from-entering-temples-during-menstruation?rq=1)) is also asking about something similar (i.e. scientific) but  it was not closed. why was the eclipse question closed then?

Comment: It was originally closed because it solicited scientific speculation, but then it was so subsequently edited, so I'm reopening it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is nothing wrong if the question is asking about mention in Hinduism.**  But the question didn't mean that initially. The OP was asking for scientific reasons.

According to our [site's policy](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), Asking for scientific speculation is off-topic.

[Political and Scientific questions are off-topic for Hinduism SE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/121/5212).

The main question you have linked i.e., [Why is Chandra Grahan (Lunar eclipse) considered unsafe for pregnant women in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3329/5212) was originally asking for scientific reasons in its body(You can check the revisions [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/revisions/3329/4)). Hence it was closed. Later it was modified to fit the requirements of the site by the OP and other users.(Check the revisions [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/revisions/3329/6)).  But the users forgot to vote to reopen the post. Now, it has been reopened by one of the moderators.

The other question you have linked i.e., [Why are women restricted from entering temples during menstruation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11321/5212), is **already closed as a duplicate** of an existing [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8/why-are-menstruating-women-at-least-in-the-brahmin-community-asked-to-be-separ).  Even scientific speculation is also valid but the users chose to vote as duplicate. It was not closed as a scientific speculation because it will work as a sign post.

Hope this helps.