# Shouldn't Stackexchange change this website structure to Question-Opinion site?

Tags: discussion

I've seen most answers are opposite from each other. On a single question, multiple answers can be correct, although they are way different, different answer.

So shouldn't it be Question-Opinion website?

Comment: By this website do you mean Hinduism Stack Exchange?

Comment: It's simple. Sanatana Dharma has various sects i.e. Sampradaya and they have different views and practices. So it's obvious that a question may receive different answers based on different sect.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? If you disagree, just write your answer. I'm not saying to change, I've just asked a question!

Comment: @Sarvabhouma yes, only Hinduism :)

Comment: @Vikas Check [What's Meta](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). Downvote on meta means disagreement with what you have asked. The downvotes mean what you have proposed is not useful.

Answer (score 5):

By this website, I assume it is Hinduism Stack Exchange. I will say **NO**, it's not an site for opinions

The answers here shouldn't be just opinions. For every question, there is definitely an answer. In some cases, only one answer is same but in other cases, there could be multiple correct answers. That doesn't mean the sit is filling with opinions.

Let us see an example where different answers could be right. This situation is already discussed in [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/5212)

> DIFFERENT AND CONTRADICTING ANSWERS
>
> There can be multiple definitions and answers for certain questions as different scriptures define them differently. In that case all answers are valid, only their contexts are different. For example, one may ask, “What is Yoga?” Users can answer it differently like below:
>
> Yoga is derived from the Sanskrit root yuj which means to join or to unite.Hence, yoga means union of two things.
>
> Yoga is equanimity. (samatvam yoga ucyate – Gita 2.48)
>
> Yoga is cessation of the mental tendencies (yoga citta vriti nirodha – Yoga Sutra 1.2)
>
> Yoga is skillfulness in action (yogah karmasu kausalam – Gita 2.50)

Another example is how Lord Ganesha was born.

1. Lord Ganesha was first made as a doll by Parvati and  given life (Padma Purana)
2. Lord Ganesha was born from gazing of Kameshwara and Lalita Tripura sundari (Brahmanda Purana).
3. Lord Ganesha was born when Shiva laughed loud. Hundreds of such beings are born. One of them is selected as leader of Ganas. (Varaha Purana)

All are correct here. But what suits the context of the question and which well is chosen as answer.

> So users should be encouraged to provide many such different answers from different scriptures and the **questioner should accept the one that fits to his context**.

Stack Exchange is not a site for opinions or discussions because people come up with real questions and expect real answers which work. People's opinions can be flawed.

- **Opinions or views change from time to time**. Consider having a discussion with a friend about a book. You didn't like that book. After reading it after 10 years, they might look like a joke and seem funny. Some opinions change from time to time. What our views are in life might not be the same after 5 years from now. So, the answers need to be edited from time to time based on mood of the user. That is a problem. But facts do not change.
- **Opinions do not work as solutions** - Opinion is what we think. This work for forums. Stack Exchange is not a forum. Forums allow answers like "This is a good question. Shows how deep you're reading a scripture. But there is a translation mistake in the verse. Rest of it is fine." These are not the answers we are looking for here.
- If there are multiple correct answers, let it be the case. Let them be posted. Good questions have good answers too. If we talk specifically about Hinduism. There are many variations to the same story and many paths to reach the same destination. That is good for the site. If a question is posted as "What happens to the soul after death of a person?", there are multiple ways to answer it using various sources. Since we encourage specific and detailed questions, better to limit the scope of answers by being specific which [belief the OP wants to know the answer](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/106) (Though it's from Christianity Meta, [it's adopted here also](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1600/5212)).

> If this site is going to succeed, it is absolutely essential that questions be answered specifically within the context of the belief system they are asked.

Again by multiple correct answers, it doesn't mean we are encouraging opinions because there are some questions where all answers are valid like a [personal advice](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/121/5212) request. From [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

If advice is allowed, there could be many differences in views of individuals which ultimately leads to debates. That is the topic where we do not want to touch.

So, if question is asking for opinion, there will be opinions. But we visit Stack Exchange for real life solutions for real life questions. So, [specific answers to the point are expected not opinions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115/357396).

There are other sites on Stack Exchange which take input from users which are kind of opinions like Workplace and Interpersonal Skills but they also give solutions which work and have specific policies in answering and just opinions and suggestions are not considered.