# Should this bounty be canceled and returned to the user?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, bounty

[What is the validity of Authoritativeness of vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14755/what-is-the-validity-of-authoritativeness-of-vedas)

This question currently has a bounty and the reason begins with:

> Are the existing proofs of Veda Apourusheyathva **valid in modern scientific world?**

Considering [comparison with/justification using modern science is off-topic here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/political-and-scientific-questions-are-off-topic-for-hinduism-se), should the bounty be canceled and returned to the user?

Comment: Haha what did you do??

Comment: And there are people who are up voting this. I'm just curious sv you being a Charvaka why are you against reason?

Comment: I'm not against reason, I'm just tired of reading answers (especially from the early days of the site) when people started mixing religion and science and started posting opinion-based answers without any references. It is difficult to vote on such content objectively and if such Q&A are allowed it will only prompt more such answers. @MrGreenGold

Comment: Totally agree I know what you are talking about. People talking about Ancient Vimanas, Kundalini or Nuclear Bomb in Ancient War. I totally agree. We have to prevent that, but preventing genuine logical questions and questions on logocal arguments would be counter productive in my opinion.

Comment: Can we at least mention the proteins that are able to form prions are almost certainly what the soul directly controls for comparison/justification with modern science? Mostly because that actually has religious implications with how can X be a child of Y despite not sharing the same genes, what counts as death and what is alive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

User asks following in bounty reasons:

> Are the existing proofs of Veda Apourusheyathva valid in modern
> scientific world?

Yes. This is off-topic and invite only speculative answers. Any user should answer from hindu philosophical perspective, either quoting Scriptures and/or works or commentaries of Hindu Acharyas.

Bounty was cancelled and returned to user.

Answer (score -1):

Now if there was a logic stack exchange or mathematics stack exchange and if some one asks a logical question its not off topic.

Now what is this Hinduism? Just Vedas and Puranas?

Hinduism is filled with philosophical and logical scriptures. There are numerous granthas dealing with Pramana. Which deals with empiricism, logic and scriptures.

As much as phala jyotisha is Hinduism, the khagola shastra is also a part of Hinduism. The books like Brihat Samhita and other works contain both.

It's invalid and outright an attack on the Hindu spirit to just reduce it to belief scriptures. It invalidates all the works of logic and science done by our Purvacharyas.

One of the main schools of Hinduism was Nyaya, which could be literally interpreted as logic. And by saying using Logic and Science is off topic would be to discredit books like Tarka Sangraha, Khandana khadya etc.

The ancient Vaisheshikas, who have been extensively referred and refuted in Brahma Sutra Bhashya of Shri Adi Shankaracharya were literally Atomists giving various reasons for their positions. So the contents of Shareeraka Bhashya which refutes them on the basis of logic in the Avirodha Adhyaya is not Hindu? Really?

Hinduism = Philosophy + Logic + Emprical Observation + Revealations of Rishis and Yogis which are Scriptures + Itihasa.

By reducing it to only Scriptures and asking references even for logical questions is reducing Hinduism from its past glory into one of the mainstream faith based religion. If you continue this non sense one day you will be silent before the Atheist who will be backed by Science and when people en mass loose faith, like its happening in west, Hindus will be unable to answer anyone, they will parrot verses from Scriptures like Zakir Naik, without having any objectivity as to why anyone should trust those books.

To curb Logical and Scientific questions and resisting the integration of Modern Science and Hinduism and calling them off topic is an offfense to Hinduism.

> Even the words heard from an ignorant person, if in themselves they be
> fraught with sense, come to be regarded as pious and wise. In days of
> old, Usanas said unto the Daityas this truth, which should remove all
> doubts, that scriptures are no scriptures if they cannot stand the
> test of reason.
> -Bhishma
> Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CXLII

---

> Even a hundred statements of sruti to the effect that fire is cold and
> non-luminous won't prove valid. If it does make such a statement, its
> import will have to be interpreted differently
> -Adi Shankaracharya, Geetha Bhashya 18.66

---

> "It is wrong to believe blindly. You must exercise your own reason and
> judgment"
> Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 1,
> Raja-Yoga, Introductory

Comment: @TheDestroyer how is logic speculative? Anumana is not speculative.