# Is Logic and Science really off topic for Hinduism Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Refer: [Political and Scientific questions are off-topic for Hinduism SE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/political-and-scientific-questions-are-off-topic-for-hinduism-se)

---

Note: I'm not outright saying people need to start asking questions regarding Modern mathematics and Quantum Physics in Hinduism Stack Exchange. All I'm saying is there are many Logical and Scientific contents in Orthodox Hindu scriptures and any question trying to discuss them independently or comparitively with Modern Science and Pure Logic should not be labelled as off topic. If someone doesn't like the question they can downvote. But flagging it off topic and closng it, thereby totally avoiding the question amd the discussion, is just against the spirit of Hinduism and the values of our Purvacharyas.

---

Now if there was a logic stack exchange or mathematics stack exchange and if some one asks a logical question its not off topic.

Now what is this Hinduism? Just Vedas and Puranas?

Hinduism is filled with philosophical and logical scriptures. There are numerous granthas dealing with Pramana. Which deals with empiricism, logic and scriptures.

As much as Phala Jyotisha is Hinduism, the Khagola Shastra is also a part of Hinduism. The books like Brihat Samhita and other works contain both.

It's invalid and outright an attack on the Hindu spirit to just reduce it to belief scriptures. It invalidates all the works of logic and science done by our Purvacharyas.

One of the main schools of Hinduism was Nyaya, which could be literally interpreted as logic. And by saying using Logic and Science is off topic would be to discredit books like Tarka Sangraha, Khandana Khanda khadya etc.

The ancient Vaisheshikas, who have been extensively referred and refuted in Brahma Sutra Bhashya of Shri Adi Shankaracharya were literally Atomists giving various reasons for their positions. So the contents of Shareeraka Bhashya which refutes them on the basis of logic in the Avirodha Adhyaya is not Hindu? Really?

Hinduism = Philosophy + Logic + Emprical Observation + Revealations of Rishis and Yogis which are Scriptures + Itihasa.

By reducing it to only Scriptures and asking references even for logical questions is reducing Hinduism from its past glory into one of the mainstream faith based religion. If you continue this non sense one day you will be silent before the Atheist who will be backed by Science and when people en mass loose faith, like its happening in west, Hindus will be unable to answer anyone, they will parrot verses from Scriptures like Zakir Naik, without having any objectivity as to why anyone should trust those books.

To curb Logical and Scientific questions and resisting the integration of Modern Science and Hinduism and calling them off topic is an offfense to Hinduism.

> Even the words heard from an ignorant person, if in themselves they be
> fraught with sense, come to be regarded as pious and wise. In days of
> old, Usanas said unto the Daityas this truth, which should remove all
> doubts, that scriptures are no scriptures if they cannot stand the
> test of reason.
> -Bhishma
> Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CXLII

---

> Even a hundred statements of sruti to the effect that fire is cold and
> non-luminous won't prove valid. If it does make such a statement, its
> import will have to be interpreted differently
> -Adi Shankaracharya, Geetha Bhashya 18.66

---

> "It is wrong to believe blindly. You must exercise your own reason and
> judgment"
> Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 1,
> Raja-Yoga, Introductory

Comment: The things you are mentioning are of larger scope and seeing so SE community already have [phylosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It is better not to allow those questions here as well. People are asking [such questions already there](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hinduism).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only scientific "speculation" is disallowed.

Nyaya/Tarka shastra are not speculation. They are scriptures that deal with Pramana (scientific epistemeology).

We already have QAs based on them like [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20116/what-are-the-nyaya-vaisheshika-arguments-against-sound-as-a-vibration-of-air) and [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20777/4435)

Comment: why have you become mar from ram??

Comment: @MrGreenGold - cos i am complete opposite of ram.

Comment: what happened?? 

Answer (score 1):

In comparison with other religions, Hinduism does not just deal with religion/beliefs but has multiple subjects in it. But this site is scoped mainly the religious part of Hinduism. For most of the other subjects, we can ask on other SE communities like:

- [Phylosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hinduism)
- [Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hinduism)
- History.SE
- Mythology.SE

If we feel like why can't we ask all things at one place i.e HSE then that might be confusing for non-experts or enthusiasts who visit this community.