# Bountied question expecting answers with "science behind religious beliefs and practices" an okay trend?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, bounty

This [recently bountied question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46484/vastu-shastra-reason) demands for an answer - scientific explanation behind the practices of vāstu-śāstra.

> I recently got interested in vastu. **What is the scientific reason of all.** I know something related to sun being there in the East but what about the other directions.

On being reiterated that 'scientific speculation are off topic', the OP retorts to condescension.

> [image]

Now, I don't have a problem with if vāstu-śāstra is indeed scientific or not. But, I think "[scientific speculations are off-topic](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/political-and-scientific-questions-are-off-topic-for-hinduism-se)" has been the stance of the community always. And, I don't find any reason here to make an exception.

So, is this allowed?

If not, can the MODS please cancel the bounty or atleast edit the "scientific-speculation" parts?

Comment: OP added bounty only for second part. i [have asked](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46484/vastu-shastra-reason#comment147922_46484) clarification from him on "scientific explanation". Let him respond

Comment: Yes, OP added bounty for the second part only. However, OP still ask scientific reasoning in the same question, which is off-topic. And I think @TheDestroyer , whenever someone mentions "scientific" they mean modern science only, unless stated otherwise. If OP wanted "philosophical aspects", they would have mentioned it. Even in that "condescending comment" the OP is very clear, what they are asking , i.e., "Modern Scientific" speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP edited question and question now just asks for "reason", not scientific reason. OP also added bounty specifically for his second question. So, question is proper now.